# Cakephp Fatal error: PaypalIpnConfig: The configuration could not be loaded.

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I did every thing mentioned in the documentation, but I am getting Fatal error. Is this plugin built for CakePHP2.x.

This plugin I have to use:https://github.com/webtechnick

Fatal error: PaypalIpnConfig: The configuration could not be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

copy this **paypal_ipn_config.php** that locates in **PaypalIpn/Config** to **App/Config**. (y)